# 17000 Lines .csv file insert into database and compare

Tags: php, sql, firebird

I have a semicolon seperated .csv with 17000 lines like this

```
SETCODE;NAME;          T;    F

THS;Cutthroat Maneuver;50226;50227

THS;Dark Betrayal;50622;50623

THS;Disciple of Phenax;50466;50467

THS;Erebos, God of the Dead;50308;50309

THS;Erebos's Emissary;50474;50475

THS;Felhide Minotaur;50332;50333

THS;Fleshmad Steed;50328;50329
```

In my firebird database I need to insert 50226 or 50227 depending on a true or false statement in my row

I can compare   Name;setcode; columns and and a column called  premium where the value is either true or false

I do not have php skills and I was wondering what would be best practice

So i need some automation for this

```
update CARDS a

set a.CARDCATID='50226'

where a.name='Cutthroat Maneuver' and a.PREMIUM='F' and a.SETCODE='THS'

or when 

set a.CARDCATID='50227'

where a.name='Cutthroat Maneuver' and a.PREMIUM='T' and a.SETCODE='THS'
```

times 17000

any help is greatly appricated

what is best practice for me to do this in flamerobin

Oops there was a code tag I forgot, Won't happen again ^^

Comment: You need to use a parametrized query (aka prepared statement).

Answer (score 0):

If you would use IBExpert instead of Flamerobin, you could use the tool "Import data" to import the csv data to a temporary table, and then write a simple procedure with for select loop and iterate over rows in this temp table.